# print contents of std::vector<std::string> in lldb

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

I want to print all the strings in a vector. When I do

```
(lldb) p myVector
(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >) $30 = size=65 {
  [0] = Summary Unavailable
  [1] = Summary Unavailable
  [2] = Summary Unavailable
  [3] = Summary Unavailable
  [4] = Summary Unavailable
  [5] = Summary Unavailable
  [6] = Summary Unavailable
  [7] = Summary Unavailable
  [8] = Summary Unavailable
  [9] = Summary Unavailable
  [10] = Summary Unavailable
  [11] = Summary Unavailable
...
```

However, printing individual elements work e.g.,

```
p myVector[5].c_str()
(const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::value_type *) $31 = 0x0000600000210280 "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS"
```

I'd like to print all elements at once as there are quite a few.

Comment: It looks like lldb's "std::string" "summary formatter" is failing for these strings.  The summary formatters grok the internal layout of the underlying object and extract a user-friendly representation therefrom.  If you can get this to happen reliably, please file a bug with the llvm issues tracker https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.  Be sure to include the system you are working on and the version of the standard C++ library you are using, these formatters do have to know the details of the standard library implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i was able to solve this by using lldb's expr evaluation

```bash
(lldb) expr -- for (int x = 0; x < myVector.size(); x++) printf("arg[%d] = %s\n", x, myVector[x].c_str())

# prints:
arg[0] = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
arg[1] = --driver-mode=g++
arg[2] = -DGTEST_HAS_RTTI=0
arg[3] = -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
arg[4] = -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
arg[5] = -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `-fstandalone-debug` to the compiler command line.

I have this set on my cmake for the debug build:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-ggdb3 -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fstandalone-debug ${SANITIZE_OPTS}" CACHE STRING "Initial debug flags")
```

Comment: This could work, but it is not always possible to change build options while debugging.

Comment: You should change the build option **before** debugging

Comment: In many cases it is not even possible to rebuild the application.